# PHP merge $_POST into $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session, post

Is there a way to take the $_POST data array and merge it into the $_SESSION array. I want it to keep the current data intact and only insert new data or update the pieces that have been changed. I've tried array_merge but it didn't do what I was looking for.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try with `array_merge`? It does exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If `array_merge()` didn't do what you wanted, you might need to come up with an example. What's your input and what output do you expect? Keep it simple.

Comment: I hope you understand the security risks involved when saving $_POST variables in $_SESSION without prior filtering of $_POST data.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not try creating a $_SESSION['postVars'] variable and then storing the $_POST information in there. I wouldn't try and merge $_SESSION with $_POST that will have security implications for your application later on down the track. Having said that I would also be careful about just saving whatever comes through on the $_POST global. Anyway, I hope my suggestion helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to try to merge `$_POST` into `$_SESSION`. Instead, do something like:

```
$_SESSION['lastPost']=$_POST;
```

Or, if you're wanting to update changes, compare `$_POST` with `$_SESSION['lastPost']` and assign any differences to the affected keys, such as

```
$_SESSION['lastPost']['thisKeysValueChanged'] = $_POST['thisKeysValueChanged'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION[$key]) || ($val !== $_SESSION[$key])) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

in short, if the currently-being-considered POST key value doesn't have a corresponding entry in the SESSION arra, or the two values differ, then copy the POST data to SESSION.

However, be aware that this would allow malicious users to overwrite the entire session array. If they know that you keep a `$_SESSION['is_admin']` flag, they can trivially overwrite it with an appropriate value and give themselves superuser powers.

Directly+blindly transferring user-provided data into the session variable is NEVER a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

array_merge does work, but it doesnt modify the array, it *returns* the merged array. What you want to do is:

```
$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $_POST);
```

(security warnings as above :)