# Why does this `$_SESSION = $_POST` fail?

Tags: php, session, post

What am I missing here? This is my PHP file:

```
<?
session_start();

echo print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<br>";
echo print_r($_POST);

// Save input in session
$_SESSION = $_POST;
echo "test1";
?>

<br>
test2
```

This file is accessed from a form submit, and I'm sure the post data exists. The output is:

> Array ( [login] => 1 ) 1
>   Array ( [name] => test [type] => test ) 1
>   test2

and it makes no sense to me. The `session` content and `post` content are printed without problems.

But the `$_SESSION = $_POST;` appears to fail, and the rest of the script until the `?>` doesn't give any response, which is obvious because the `test1` text isn't printed.

I can't find out what happens with the `$_SESSION = $_POST;`. All questions I find on SO and elsewhere gives this way to store post data in the session.

I'm aware that `session_start();` is needed prior to any output. Is there something else that is also needed in this case?

What am I missing?

---

**Update - Test file**

The exact code of a full test file (*link removed*) is:

```
<?
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?

echo print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<br>";
echo print_r($_POST);

// Save input in session
$_SESSION = $_POST;
echo "test1";
?>

<p>test2</p>

<form method="post" action="test.php">
    Type something to test: <input type="text" name="testfield" id="testfield">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Update - Solved?**

Okay, it is solved now. But this is STRANGE...

The problem appearently is caused by the comment. The `//` stops the script from running within the `<?..?>` brackets. When I remove the comment `// Save input in session`, then it works...?

Now WHAT am I missing here? It must be some php setting or something. Or maybe some file or script data that was changed. I guess that since @CodeCaster had it working, something happens on my PC that does it... But comments work anywhere else? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: you `echo "test1"` and you get a result with `test2` ? is it the same script? is anything submitted with `post` method to that script?

Comment: Please post the actual code, since the code you posted does work. Also if PHP seems to "fail without printing anything", enable error reporting.

Comment: Corrected. I missed the last to lines

Comment: This is not the actual code, please test it for yourself. This works, and prints `test1` too.

Comment: @CodeCaster. Yes, it is the actual code. I have made a test file for you to see. See my update above. The `test1` text doesn't show.

Comment: Yes it does, it's behind the `Array ( [testfield] => ) 1test1`.

Comment: Really?! I can't see it. Not in Chrome, IE9 or Firefox... Is that line you wrote a copy/paste from the ouput that you see @CodeCaster?

Comment: It shows me that on PHP 5.3.5 from XAMPP 1.7.4 on my test machine when I use your code.

Comment: Solution found. See my update. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703611/using-notepad-comments-in-php-stops-the-script/11703647#11703647 meaning that the problem was different than I thought. Thanks for all tips and tricks.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];` instead?

I've never used `$_SESSION = $_POST;`, and neither never seen it, in the whole time I programmed on PHP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, and good idea. It makes no difference though if I use `$_SESSION = $_POST;` or `$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];` :(.

Comment: `$_SESSION = $_POST;` works fine though. But the current session is then overwritten.

Comment: great :) if you have authentication, don't forget to verify the $_POST vars as ic can be used to hack into your site.

Comment: Agreed with @peteroak, and assigning one by one make it easier to make specific verifications on each var.

Answer (score 2):

i would instead `foreach` the $_POST and add it to `$_SESSION['mypostvars']`. Keep in mind that you should validate and verify the $_POST before storing them.

this is a possible duplicated of [PHP merge $_POST into $_SESSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570222/php-merge-post-into-session)

Comment: Yes, I ended up using `foreach`. If I just used `$_SESSION = $_POST;` the current session would be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Working with Xampp, that example works just fine.  The 'test1' is printed on the before and after a successful post.  Using PHP 5.3.8.

Tested on Linux with PHP 5.3.6, also works fine printing the 'test1' in both cases.

So, it seems PHP is not the problem here.

Comment: Nope, PHP wasn't the problem here :) Se my update. The problem was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703611/using-notepad-comments-in-php-stops-the-script/11703647#11703647.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify $_SESSION but I don't think you're allowed to reassign it like that.  Instead, copy the members of $_POST into it. Try using array_merge() but if that doesn't work then write a foreach loop to do it.