# Using Notepad++, comments `//` in PHP stops the script

Tags: php, comments, notepad++

The issue started with this question: [Why does this `$_SESSION = $_POST` fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701179/why-does-this-session-post-fail)

After some time I found that my problem described in that question is caused by the comment `//` in PHP (as described in the last update in the question).

I suspect my editor Notepad++ to have some kind of influence on this.

As an example, if I write:

```
<?
echo "test1<br>";
echo "test2<br>";
echo "test3<br>";
// Comment
echo "test4<br>";
echo "test5<br>";
?>
<?
echo "test6<br>";
echo "test7<br>";
echo "test8<br>";
?>
```

everything after the comment `// Comment` inside the current `<?...?>` is ignored. The output to the above is thus:

> test1
>   test2
>   test3
>   test6
>   test7
>   test8

The other kind of comments `/*...*/` works fine.

Strangely it only happens on comments that I edit or create. All other untouched comments do no harm. There might be some Notepad++ setting causing this that I don't know of. If have experienced before that "invisible" things happen when you fiddle around with the program, so I might have done something wrong at somepoint.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your line endings! Save the file with unix style line endings. (Edit > EOL Conversion > UNIX format)

Comment: How do you do that in Notepad++?