# Post variables in session storage logs user out

Tags: php, session

I'm having a issue with my login system, when people login and visits pages it works perfectly but as soon as they go to my page where I have `$_SESSION = $_POST;` written on the first line makes users log out automatically.

I have a cookie expire time set on the login system but for some reason users get logged off when they go to that specific site. I removed that code then it worked fine.

Any idea?

---

Edit: 
I'm using php login advanced system, http://www.php-login.net/. This isn't necessary to read the code because it's a issue with session and the posts. So I'm just wondering what the issue can be.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking; show *actual* code.

Comment: If you store login state in the session and then do `$_SESSION = $_POST;` that overwrites everything that was in the session.

Comment: How do I make it not overwrite it and still be able to use $_SESSION = $_POST. Because I want to transfer POST to another page using header location. So this was the way I thought about it. @AbraCadaver

Comment: I've used that system before with no problems at all. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. You have enough to debug.

Comment: $_REQUEST has post data and cookies, so maybe that's what you want to set $_SESSION to?

Comment: $_SESSION['my_cache'] = $_POST;

Comment: That did work but the $_POST isn't transfered to the second site. @JohnGreen

Comment: Plus, read up on `$_SESSION` http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
```

so that you store the post data in a sub-section of $_SESSION. Right now you're completely TRASHING your entire session and replacing whatever was there with the POST data.

Comment: How do I read the post on my second site, example $_POST['username'].

Comment: it's just an array. `$_SESSION['post']['postfieldthatyouwant']`.

Comment: Thanks I'm quite new to PHP, and this helped me out with my problem. I'll be thinking of this solution in the future. Accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy over every individual field from `$_POST` to `$_SESSION`, you could use something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: That's dangerous because you don't know what the fields are.  They could conflict with the fields he's relying on for login.  You want to put it in a sub-key.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the best solution to use, but it was what he was asking about how to do.

Comment: Hence why Marc's solution is better.  Analagous to yours if you add a subkey: 
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
}

Comment: Not arguing that his isn't the better of the two choices.

Answer (score -3):

```
$_SESSION = array array_merge ( $_SESSION , $_POST );
```

if u really need it http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

but [Why does this `$_SESSION = $_POST` fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701179/why-does-this-session-post-fail)

```
$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

is in any way a bad idea, `$_POST` is not save!